# Qt proper usage of properties syntax

Tags: c++, qt

When I use `Q_PROPERTY` to define a property, I make sure to inherit from `QObject` and to declare the `Q_OBJECT` macro in the beginning of class definition. I declare the property like this:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QString MyProp READ getMyProp WRITE setMyProp)
```

and then I use it like this:

```
myObject->MyProp = QString("test");
```

And it tells me that there is no such member as `MyProp`. What is the problem?

Comment: `myObject->setProperty("MyPro", QString("test"));`  works?

Comment: @t3ft3l--i Yeah, but I thought it was supposed to allow you to use them like normal members? Otherwise what's the point?

Comment: "Otherwise what's the point?" Other Qt systems use them to provide a generic interference to all `QObject` derived types, e.g. QML binding.

Comment: @ulakblade `Q_PROPERTY` is the best way to integrate C++ logical code in QML-based applications. And one more point is using the methods of class without knowing they are appear

Comment: @t3ft3l--i property() returns a QVariant, does this mean if I have properties of objects of types that aren't default to QVariant, I have to use Q_DECLARE_METATYPE for every one of them or does Q_PROPERTY handle this?

Comment: @ulakblade Of cource you need to declare new types. There is no links between properties of your custom class and `QVariant::value()` method. See workaround this issue at [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#value) using `canConvert()` or default constructor of class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course there is no such member, since you yourself have said that a getter is called `getMyProp`, and the setter is called `setMyProp`. The definition of a member called `MyProp` is completely up to you. Below, I'll show how you could define such members.

We should also note that in Qt it is customary not to prepend the getter with `get`, but simply name it after the property. Thus you'd have

```
Q_PROPERTY(int foo READ foo WRITE setFoo)
// rather than
Q_PROPERTY)int foo READ getFoo WRITE setFoo)
```

The possible solutions include:

(1) Access the property's data member directly - this breaks the encapsulation granted by the property system, and wouldn't be advised.

```
class Direct : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(int prop MEMBER prop)
public:
  int prop;
};

Direct d;
d.prop = 3;
Q_ASSERT(d.property("prop").toInt() == 3);
```

The last line works because *moc* generates the trivial getter and setter code that is then accessible through the meta object system. This code is embedded in the metadata implementation and doesn't result in any methods being added to the class itself.

(2) Have a getter that returns a reference. This is the simplest, low overhead approach when getter and setter are trivial.

```
class GetSet : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(int prop READ prop WRITE setProp)
  int m_prop;
public:
  int & prop() { return m_prop; }
  int prop() const { return m_prop; }
  void setProp(int prop) { m_prop = prop; }
};

GetSet gs;
gs.prop() = 3; // assignment syntax through "getter"
Q_ASSERT(gs.property("prop").toInt() == 3);
gs.setProp(4); // setter syntax
Q_ASSERT(gs.property("prop").toInt() == 4);
```

(3) Expose members that act as a proxy to the property. This allows to use the proxy without the call syntax: `obj.prop` instead of `obj.prop()`.

(3a) We can use the Qt property system to access a named property. The `QMetaProperty` acts as a cache to avoid repeated name lookup on each property access. A `QVariant` conversion is performed on each property access.

```
template <typename B, typename T> class PProxy {
  Q_DISABLE_COPY(PProxy)
  B * obj;
  QMetaProperty prop;
public:
  PProxy(B & o, const char * p) : obj(&o), 
    prop(o.metaObject()->property(o.metaObject()->indexOfProperty(p))) {}
  T operator=(const T & val) { prop.write(obj, val); return val; }
  T operator=(T && val) { prop.write(obj, val); return val; }
  operator T() const { return prop.read(obj).value<T>(); }
};

class ViaPProxy : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(int prop READ getProp WRITE setProp)
  int m_prop;
public:
  PProxy<Direct, int> prop;
  ViaPProxy() : prop(*this, "prop") {}
  int getProp() const { return m_prop; }
  void setProp(int val) { m_prop = val; }
}

ViaPProxy vpp;
vpp.prop = 3; // invokes the setter through a proxy
Q_ASSERT(vpp.prop == 3);
```

(3b) Instead of going through the Qt property system and `QVariant` conversions, the proxy can use the getter and setter directly. This has lower overhead than (3a), but requires that the getter and optionally setter exist.

```
template <typename B, typename T, 
          T (B::*get)() const, void (B::*set)(T) = 0> class DProxy {
  Q_DISABLE_COPY(DProxy)
  B & obj;
public:
  DProxy(B & o) : obj(o) {}
  T operator=(const T & val) { (obj.*set)(val); return val; }
  T operator=(T && val) { (obj.*set)(std::forward<T>(val)); return val; }
  operator T() const { return (obj.*get)(); }
};

class ViaDProxy : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(int prop READ getProp WRITE setProp)
  int m_prop;
public:
  DProxy<Direct, int, &ViaDProxy::get, &ViaDProxy::set> prop;
  ViaDProxy() : prop(*this) {}
  int getProp() const { return m_prop; }
  void setProp(int val) { m_prop = val; }
}

ViaDProxy vdp;
vdp.prop = 3; // invokes the setter through a proxy
Q_ASSERT(vdp.prop == 3);
```