# How to enforce/automatically use a C++ setter method? (like ObjC)

Tags: c++, objective-c, variables, syntax, setter

In `Objective-C`, it is possible to use `@properties` that run a setter method (as specified by the implementation) when using a simple increment (`++`) call on an instance's value for that property.  Here's an example...

```
@import Foundation;

@interface Z : NSObject 
@property (nonatomic) int intVar; 
@end

@implementation Z

- (void) setIntVar:(int)i {
    printf("intVar is now %i.\n", _intVar = i); 
    // I could do other things here, too.
}
@end

int main() { Z *z = Z.new; z.intVar++; }
```

> `intVar is now 1.`

I am new to `C++`, but have been unable (as of yet) to find a way to recreate this behavior with `class` "member variables".  For example...

```
#include <iostream>

class X {

    public:
        void setIntVar(int x) { printf("setting intvar to: %i\n", _intVar = x); }
        int _intVar;
};

X instanceOfX;

int main() {

    instanceOfX._intVar++;
    printf("X's intvar is %i\n", instanceOfX._intVar);
    instanceOfX.setIntVar(instanceOfX._intVar + 1);
}
```

> `X's intvar is 1`
>
> `setting intvar to: 2`

The difference is subtle, but I am just wondering if there is a way to enforce the setter for incrementing (or setting, even), without making the variable private.

Comment: Best I can come up with is to create a custom class for `_intVar` that defines an `operator++` which calls `setIntVar`. That's rather clunky, though.

Comment: MSVC has an (icompatible) C++ extension for properties: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfk0thd.aspx

Comment: You may read: http://seanmiddleditch.com/why-c-does-not-need-c-like-properties/

Comment: A commonly used approach is to have proxy objects that stand in for the real value. The proxy object can be accessed by value, but is not an integer; it only acts as an integer would: you can set it, or get its value, but it intercepts any such accesses. See the `DProxy` template in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31574917/1329652) for an example.